# libimobiledevice returning weird characters

Tags: java, c, jna, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to pair with a connected iOS device and get the UDID using libimobiledevice and JNA. This is how I have declared the native functions:

```
static native int idevice_new(PointerByReference device, Pointer udid);
static native int lockdownd_client_new(Pointer device, PointerByReference client, String label);
static native int idevice_get_udid(Pointer idevice, StringByReference udid);
static native int lockdownd_query_type(Pointer lockdownd_client, StringByReference type);
```

For testing, I'm trying to do exactly what running the command `idevicepair pair` does.

This is my main method:

```
PointerByReference device = new PointerByReference();
System.out.println("idevice_new error code: " + idevice_new(device, Pointer.NULL));
PointerByReference client = new PointerByReference();
System.out.println("lockdownd_client_new error code: " + lockdownd_client_new(device.getValue(), client, "java"));
StringByReference udid = new StringByReference();
System.out.println("idevice_get_udid error code: " + idevice_get_udid(device.getValue(), udid));
System.out.println("udid: " + udid.getValue());
StringByReference type = new StringByReference();
System.out.println("lockdownd_query_type error code: " + lockdownd_query_type(client.getValue(), type));
System.out.println("lockdownd_query_type: " + type.getValue());
System.out.println("lockdownd_pair error code: " + lockdownd_pair(client.getValue(), Pointer.NULL));
```

Whenever I try to get any string value, it outputs these weird question mark characters:

```
idevice_new error code: 0
lockdownd_client_new error code: 0
idevice_get_udid error code: 0
udid: ��AZ�
lockdownd_query_type error code: 0
lockdownd_query_type: �HbZ�
lockdownd_pair error code: 0
```

The characters are different each time.

In case you can't see it:

[image: program output]

Comment: Why did you tag this with C?

Comment: @Bwebb Since libimobiledevice is made in C

Comment: ok, im not sure how much sense that makes but looking over your java printfs it looks like your printing random memory.  "udid: " + udid.getValue()" is passed as a println arg but i dont see where udid value is ever set.  Where is that memory supposed to be assigned?

Comment: @Bwebb It's supposed to be assigned in `idevice_get_udid()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UUID changes every time because it is unique! Each new one generated is different.

As for the strange characters, your mapping of the `uuid` (and also `type`) to `StringByReference` is the culprit here, as you're not getting the data in the format it's stored in natively.

The method signature in C (which you should have posted with your question) notes that the type of `uuid` is `**char`, a Pointer to a pointer to a string of 8-bit C values.  Digging into the source code, it appears they are the digits 0-9 and A-F in a string representation, and either 32 bytes (without hyphens) or 36 bytes (with) plus the null terminator.  (Note this isn't always obvious; they could have been stored in 16 bytes as the full byte value, something the API should actually document.)

Internally, the `StringByReference` class uses the `Pointer.getString()` method:

```
public String getValue() {
    return getPointer().getString(0);
}
```

The [getString() method](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getString-long-) with only an offset uses your platform's default encoding, which is probably a multi-byte character set.  This may not (and obviously doesn't, in your case) match the 8-bit encoding of the UUID.

You should map the UUID as a `PointerByReference` and use `uuid.getValue().getString(0, "UTF-8")` or `uuid.getValue().getString(0, "US-ASCII")` to fetch the String as the 8-bit characters they represent.

(Alternately, you could get a byte array and create a String from it, although I'm not sure if you'll get the 32- or 36-byte result, so have fun if you go that route. For true fun, you can iterate the offset and read byte-by-byte until you get 0.  But I digress.)

Doing the same thing for the `type` field is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've spent ages trying to get it to work (I wish I could upvote you multiple times)